# How do I use a select query to display data from two tables where it concatenate the data into one cell when displaying in PL SQL?

Tags: sql, database, select, plsql, concatenation

I have two tables :

Table 1 ->

- Name  - Age - Country
- David | 14  | USA
- Beth  | 23  | UK
- Josh  | 32  | UK

Table 2 ->

- Text1 | Text2  | Text3
- Boy1 | Age1 | Count1
- Girl2 | Age2 | Count2
- Boy3 | Age3 | Count3

Desired Result ->

- David Boy1 | 14 Age1 | USA Count1
- Beth Girl2 | 23 Age2 | UK Count2
- Josh Boy3 | 32 Age3 | UK Count3

NOTE : The two tables have the same number of rows and columns, and the first cell (1,1) from Table 1 corresponds to (1,1) from Table 2.

Table 1 aslo has a primary key that can be used as a foreign key for table 2.(not shown here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.Name + ' ' + t2.text1,
    t1.age + ' ' + t2.text2, 
    t1.country + ' ' + t2.text3 
  FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 
  WHERE t1.ROWNUM = t2.ROWNUM;
```

Then you will get output as

```
David Boy1 | 14 Age1 | USA Count1
Beth Girl2 | 23 Age2 | UK Count2
Josh Boy3  | 32 Age3 | UK Count3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT
      T1.NAME || T2.TEXT1,
      T1.AGE || T2.TEXT2,
      T1.COUNTRY || T2.TEXT3
FROM
      TABLE1 T1,
      TABLE2 T2
WHERE
      T1.ROWNUM = T2.ROWNUM;
```